# How to plot a graph of arbitrary points in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri}

  \begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}

          [
          place/.style={circle,draw=red,fill=red,thick}]


        \draw[help lines,->] (0,0) -- (10,0);                               
        \draw[help lines,->] (0,0) -- (0,10);   % draw axis lines             
        \draw[gray,dashed] (0,10) -- (10,10);   % draw asymptote              

        % place points on the graph

        \node at (1,2) [place] {};
        \node at (2,1) [place] {};
        \node at (3,0.5) [place] {};
        \node at (4,0.25) [place] {};
        \node at (5,7) [place] {};
        \node at (6,6) [place] {};
        \node at (7,2) [place] {};
        \node at (8,4) [place] {};
        \node at (9,9) [place] {};
        \node at (10,9.8) [place] {};


    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

Which produces this result:

[image]

I have two questions:

1. What I wanted was for each point on the graph to be represented by a solid red circle, not an unfilled black circle. (See code above.) What did I do wrong?
2. The next step here is to connect those points with a curve. What is the best way to do so in `tikz`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove all spaces when declaring the options for your `tikzpicture` and you'll get the nodes displayed properly.

To connect the nodes, assign them names containing increasing numbers and then draw the lines easily with a `\foreach` statement.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[place/.style={circle,draw=red,fill=red,thick}]
  \draw[help lines,->] (0,0) -- (10,0);                               
  \draw[help lines,->] (0,0) -- (0,10);                
  \draw[gray,dashed] (0,10) -- (10,10);   
  \node (n1) at (1,2) [place] {};
  \node (n2) at (2,1) [place] {};
  \node (n3) at (3,0.5) [place] {};
  \node (n4) at (4,0.25) [place] {};
  \node (n5) at (5,7) [place] {};
  \node (n6) at (6,6) [place] {};
  \node (n7) at (7,2) [place] {};
  \node (n8) at (8,4) [place] {};
  \node (n9) at (9,9) [place] {};
  \node (n10) at (10,9.8) [place] {};

  \foreach \x [evaluate={\y=int(\x+1);}] in {1,...,9}
  \draw (n\x) -- (n\y);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In this very case the code could be shortened as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[place/.style={circle,fill=red,thick}]
  \foreach \x/\y in {1/2, 2/1, 3/0.5, 4/0.25, 5/7, 6/6, 7/2, 8/4, 9/9, 10/9.8} {
    \node (n\x) at (\x,\y) [place] {};
  }
  \foreach \x [evaluate={\y=int(\x+1);}] in {1,...,9} {
    \draw (n\x) -- (n\y);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**BUT**, if you are "only" trying to draw a *plot* and don't want to mess with nodes, then you may consider using `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    title=Title,
    xlabel=$x$ coordinate,
    ylabel=$y$ coordinate,]
    \addplot coordinates {(1,2) (2,1) (3,0.5) (4,0.25) (5,7) (6,6) (7,2) (8,4) (9,9) (10,9.8)};
    % if you want the plot to be RED, instead write: \addplot [red,mark=*] coordinates ...
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you use `pgfplots`, can you label the points on the graph? I didn't put that into the MWE, but it's an important part of the finished graph.

Comment: @crmdgn: Yes, it is possible. Have a look at "Two dimensional plot types" (Sec. 4.5 [`pgfplots` manual](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf).)

Comment: @PierPaolo : Let us assume that you generated the points using "foreach" .  Can you save them in a buffer and then use them \addplot3d? I assume that there is an addplot3d (right?) . Furthermore, if you have already some axes and labels, I would not like "\begin{axis}" to introduce new axes, and I would like all the relative distances inside and outside of "\begin{axis} \end{axis}" to be preserved.  Is this possible?   Thanks.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo: I don't quite understand what you mean when you talk about the buffer, but it is possible to plot curves in 3D: the macro you are looking for is `\addplot3` (to be used in a simple `axis` environment. It is used also to plot surfaces and grids.) Moreover, it is possible to superimpose multiple plots on the same axis environment: just add as many `\addplot`s as necessary. It is also possible to read data from a file (have a look at the `pgfplotstable` package). If this doesn't answer your question, please consider to post a new question, maybe adding a link to this one.